# How to Unit Test Linq Where() which has a method call in c#

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, moq, xunit

My Source code has

```
var results = searchContext.GetQueryable<Model>().Where(GetSearchPredicate()).GetResults();
private Expression<Func<Model, bool>> GetSearchPredicate()
{
    Expression<Func<Model, bool>> filterSearch = x => true;
    filterSearch = filterSearch.And(GetTemplateFilterPredicate());
    return filterSearch;
}
```

here GetTemplateFilterPredicate is another private method which does some more filter.

My Unit Test logic is

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
    public void GetEvent_ReturnResult()
    {
        var Obj = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model
                {
                    Name="testname123",
                    TemplateName="Analysis",
                    Id = "123",
                    Description="TestDescription123",
                }
        }.AsEnumerable();
        var searchContext = Substitute.For<IProviderSearchContext>();
        var queryable = new LuceneProviderQueryableStub<Model>(Obj);
        searchContext.GetQueryable<Model>().Returns(queryable);

        var mockRepo = new Mock<AnalysisService>();
        mockRepo.Protected()
            .Setup<IProviderSearchContext>("GetSearchContext")
            .Returns(searchContext);

        // Act
        var result = mockRepo.Object.Get("123");
        //Assert
    }
```

My LuceneProviderQueryableStub is

```
public class LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement> : IOrderedQueryable<TElement>, IOrderedQueryable, IQueryProvider, IQueryable<TElement>
{
    private readonly EnumerableQuery<TElement> innerQueryable;

    public Type ElementType { get { return ((IQueryable)innerQueryable).ElementType; } }

    public Expression Expression { get { return ((IQueryable)innerQueryable).Expression; } }

    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return this; } }

    public LuceneProviderQueryableStub(IEnumerable<TElement> enumerable)
    {
        innerQueryable = new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(enumerable);
    }
    public LuceneProviderQueryableStub(Expression expression)
    {
        innerQueryable = new EnumerableQuery<TElement>(expression);
    }
    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        expression = new FilterCallsReplacer().Visit(expression);
        return new LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement>((IEnumerable<TElement>)((IQueryProvider)innerQueryable).CreateQuery(expression));
    }
    public IQueryable<TElement1> CreateQuery<TElement1>(Expression expression)
    {
        expression = new FilterCallsReplacer().Visit(expression);
        return (IQueryable<TElement1>)new LuceneProviderQueryableStub<TElement>((IEnumerable<TElement>)((IQueryProvider)innerQueryable).CreateQuery(expression));
    }
    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        var items = this.ToArray();
        object results = new SearchResults<TElement>(items.Select(s => new SearchHit<TElement>(0, s)), items.Length);
        return (TResult)results;
    }
    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<TElement>)innerQueryable).GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

```
internal class FilterCallsReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo FilterMethod = typeof(QueryableExtensions)
        .GetMethod(nameof(QueryableExtensions.Filter), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    private static readonly MethodInfo WhereMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(method => method.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where));

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        return IsFilterMethod(node)
            ? RewriteToWhere(node)
            : base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
    private static bool IsFilterMethod(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        return node.Method.IsGenericMethod && node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() == FilterMethod;
    }
    private Expression RewriteToWhere(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        var arguments = node.Arguments.ToArray();
        var type = node.Method.GetGenericArguments().First();
        var whereMethod = WhereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);

        return Expression.Call(whereMethod, arguments);
    }
}
```

My expectation is to bypass the query and return Mock data.
But what happened is the debugger hits the private method in Where query which should not happen.

I am new to Unit testing and not sure of the stub for Where clause which has private method call.

How should we write stub for this?

Comment: Where is this `QueryableExtensions` class from?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem stems from the behavior of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` predicates and LINQ's execution model. When you use a method like `GetSearchPredicate()` in a `Where()` clause, it doesn't "run" immediately, but builds up an expression tree that is evaluated later when the data is actually enumerated. Therefore, when you stub out `GetQueryable<Model>()` with your `LuceneProviderQueryableStub`, it will still need to evaluate the `Where(GetSearchPredicate())` part of the expression, which invokes the private method.

To unit test this correctly, we need to stub or mock the behavior of the `Where` method such that it doesn't evaluate `GetSearchPredicate()`. There are a few different ways you could approach this:

**1. Isolate the Logic:** Refactor the method to separate the data retrieval logic from the filtering logic. You can then test each part independently. For instance, test that `GetSearchPredicate()` returns the correct predicate given certain conditions, and test that your data retrieval method correctly retrieves data given a certain predicate.

**2. Use a Mocking Framework to Bypass the Where Clause:** You're using NSubstitute, but it's more challenging to mock extension methods like `Where()`. You could consider using Moq, which supports mocking extension methods, albeit with a bit of a workaround.

**3. Stub Out the Entire Where Method:** You could go deeper with stubbing and replace the entire `Where` method, but this is complex and makes the test less intuitive.

Let's try the second approach with Moq:

**csharp**

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void GetEvent_ReturnResult()
{
    var Obj = new List<Model>
    {
        new Model
        {
            Name="testname123",
            TemplateName="Analysis",
            Id = "123",
            Description="TestDescription123",
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Model>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Model>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(Obj.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Model>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(Obj.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Model>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(Obj.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Model>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(Obj.GetEnumerator());

    mockSet.Setup(m => m.Where(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Model, bool>>>())).Returns(Obj); // Bypass the Where

    var mockContext = new Mock<YourDbContext>(); // Replace with your actual DbContext type
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<Model>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    // ... Rest of the setup for your test

    var result = mockRepo.Object.Get("123");

    //Assert
}
```

This setup uses Moq to create a mock of `DbSet<Model>`, which represents your queryable data. You then bypass the `Where` method to return the unfiltered data directly. This way, `GetSearchPredicate()` and the private methods it calls are not executed.

However, remember that this is just one approach. The key to unit testing is isolating units of functionality, so the refactoring approach might be the most maintainable and clear in the long run.

Comment: Not tested, you didn't spot the exception that is thrown.